# Manipulations of big oh notation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose we have

$$ v_j^{n+1} = v_j^n + (v_j^n)_t \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) $$

$$ v_{j+1}^{n} = v_j^n + (v_j^n)_x \Delta x + O(\Delta x^2) $$

$$ v_{j-1}^{n} = v_j^n - (v_j^n)_x \Delta x + O(\Delta x^2) $$

When trying to substitute this into

$$ \frac{ v_j^{n+1} - 1/2(v_{j+1}^n + v_{j-1}^n) }{\Delta t } + \frac{ v_{j+1}^n - v_{j-1}^n }{2 \Delta x} $$

I obtain for the first term:

$$ \frac{ v_j^n + (v_j^n)_t \Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) - 1/2[ v_j^n + (v_j^n)_x \Delta x + O(\Delta x^2) + v_j^n - (v_j^n)_t \Delta x + O(\Delta x^2) ] }{\Delta t} = \frac{ O(\Delta t) + O (\Delta x^2) }{\Delta t}$$

and the second term reduces to

$$ \frac{ v_j^n + (v_j^n)_x \Delta x + O(\Delta x^2)  - v_{j-1}^{n} - v_j^n +(v_j^n)_t \Delta x - O(\Delta x^2) }{\Delta x} = \frac{ O(\Delta x)}{\Delta x} $$

Adding up the error we obtain

$$ O(1) + O( \Delta x^2/ \Delta t) + O(1) $$

Which is what is on my answer key that is $O(\Delta x) + O(\Delta t)$. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What equation is this approximation for? Are the first formulas correct? I would have expected an x-derivative in the third formula.

Comment: it is indeed a x-derivative. I just fixed it

Comment: Im trying to show that lax friedich scheme is consistent with $v_t + a v_x =0 $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symmetric nature of the scheme 
$$
0=\frac{ v_j^{n+1} - \frac12(v_{j+1}^n + v_{j-1}^n) }{\Delta t } + a\frac{ v_{j+1}^n - v_{j-1}^n }{2 \Delta x}
$$
for $0=v_t+av_x$ suggests that it is second order at least in the $x$ direction. 
Let's test this. Suppose that the values $v_j^n$ are samples of an exact solution
\begin{align}
\frac12(v_{j+1}^n + v_{j-1}^n)&=v_j^n+\frac12(v_{xx})_j^nΔx^2+O(Δx^4)\\
\frac12(v_{j+1}^n - v_{j-1}^n)&=(v_x)_j^nΔx+\frac16(v_{xxx})_j^nΔx^3+O(Δx^5)\\
v_j^{n+1}=v_j^n+(v_t)_j^nΔt+\frac12(v_{tt})_j^nΔt^2+O(Δt^3)\\[1em]\hline
\frac{ v_j^{n+1} - \frac12(v_{j+1}^n + v_{j-1}^n) }{\Delta t } + a\frac{ v_{j+1}^n - v_{j-1}^n }{2 \Delta x}
&=(v_t)_j^n+\frac12(v_{tt})_j^nΔt+O(Δt^2)
-\frac{\frac12(v_{xx})_j^nΔx^2+O(Δx^4)}{Δt}\\
&\qquad+a((v_x)_j^n+\frac16(v_{xxx})_j^nΔx^2+O(Δx^4))\\[.5em]
&=\frac12(v_{xx})_j^n\left(a^2Δt-\frac{Δx^2}{Δt}\right)+O\left(Δt^2,Δx^2,\frac{Δx^4}{Δt}\right)
\end{align}
So if the ratio of the step sizes is fixed as $Δx=|a|Δt$, then the first term vanishes and the error is of size $O(Δt^2)$. If that ratio is not fixed that way, but still bounded to a finite range away from $0$, that is $Δx\sim Δt$ are of the same scale, then the error will indeed have the magnitude $O(Δx)+O(Δt)$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have a question. by $O( \Delta t^2, \Delta^2 x, \frac{ \Delta x^4 }{\Delta t} )$ do you mean it to  be 

$$ O( \Delta t^2) + O( \Delta^2 x) + O ( \frac{ \Delta x^4 }{\Delta t} ) $$

??

Comment: Yes, I was using this ideal-motivated notation as a shorter form.

Comment: Ok, so if we dont assume anything, then that term would be the truncation error, correct? but, how then this would tend to zero as $\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0$? So as to have consistency.

Comment: As I said, you will need some relation $cΔt\le Δx\le dΔt$ so that the quotient in the second term has a controlled value.

Comment: In your equation, in the last equality, how $(v_{tt})_j^n$ dissapear?

Comment: By applying the given PDE twice, $v_{tt}=a^2v_{xx}$.